# Runtime error using Xamarin Android with F# and ReactiveUI

Tags: android, xamarin, f#, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I have created a Xamarin Android project that is using F# and ReactiveUI.

When loading my Dashboard, I encounter a runtime exception (of type `MissingMethodException`) on the `inherit` line of this code snippet:

```
type DashboardViewModel(?host: IScreen) =
    inherit ReactiveViewModel()
    let host = LocateIfNone host
    member __.Title with get() = "Dashboard"
    interface IRoutableViewModel with
        member __.HostScreen = host
        member __.UrlPathSegment = "Dashboard"
```

The error message reads

> Method 'Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr.Deserialize40' not found.

The `ReactiveViewModel` type is a thin wrapper around `ReactiveObject`:

```
type ReactiveViewModel() as this =
    inherit ReactiveObject()
    let mutable message = noMessage
    let uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
    member __.SyncContext with get() = uiContext
    member this.Message 
        with get() = message 
        and set(value) = 
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(&message, value, "Message") |> ignore
            if message <> noMessage then this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(&message, noMessage, "Message") |> ignore
    member val MessageSent = 
        this.WhenAnyValue(toLinq <@ fun vm -> vm.Message @>).ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Where(fun m -> m <> noMessage) with get
```

The project is open source: at the moment, it contains very little content. It can be found at https://github.com/SpiegelSoft/Astrid.

I have submitted a bug on the Xamarin bug tracker: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51000

Are there any known fixes I can implement myself, so that I can close the bug of my own accord?

**UPDATE 1**

I've been investigating this issue this weekend.

The FSharp.Core version that is loaded is stuck on the obsolete version 2.3.98.1. This corresponds to the `FSharp.Core.dll` file in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0

I have tried to remove this version and load the NuGet package FSharp.Core; however, when I build the Android project, the path always reverts to the obsolete file in the Reference Assemblies path.

Is there a way to override this behaviour?

**UPDATE 2**

Replacing the `FSharp.Core.dll` file in the `Reference Assemblies` path fixes the issue, but this is a very unsatisfactory sticking plaster, which I can't ask my users to apply. Ideally, I would like to find a way to prevent the `.Droid` project from loading `FSharp.Core` from the GAC rather than the NuGet package.

Comment: I'd guess that `MissingMemberException` is equivalent to `MissingMethodException`. If so, some of the existing posts here may be of help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bf%23%5D+MissingMethodException

Comment: My mistake -- it was a `MissingMethodException`. Question amended.

Comment: Those are, IME, always caused by versioning conflicts.

Comment: And these can usually be fixed by binding redirects. Unfortunately, my project is a Xamarin Android project, so I can't use an app.config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into a very similar issue the other day. My android app had a reference to a Profile7 F# PCL library, which made use of List.unfold, which I believe was introduced in F# 4. When I used the library in my app, I saw a  MissingMethodException similar to what you are seeing. The version of FSharp.Core that Xamarin references by default when creating a new Android app didn't have this newer method.  I got around it by editing the .fsproj file for the app to remove the original reference to FSharp.Core, and replaced it with a reference to the newer version ( I copy/pasted the  tag from the PCL .fsproj file). It looks something like this:

```
<Reference Include="FSharp.Core">
   <Name>FSharp.Core</Name>
   <Private>True</Private>
   <AssemblyName>FSharp.Core.dll</AssemblyName>
   <HintPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETCore\$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion)\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I was suprised to find that this seems to have fixed the problem for me.  I'm not sure if I'll run into other issues down the line, but it may be worth trying this if you havent already.

**UPDATE** If this doesn't work immediately, follow the sequence of steps in Rob Lyndon's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried this, but unfortunately it didn't work for me, so I need to do a bit more digging. I'm sure it is a versioning issue with FSharp.Core, but it is less clear what I would have to do to remedy the situation.

Comment: I can confim that this is the correct way to solve this issue. Have a look at the bug I submitted (listed in the question) for a detailed description of the problem. You should have no problems with your fix.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this has been fixed by the GitHub commit

> https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/commit/df41af046000556ed82f638e8041b7f718966a92

which removes FSharp.Core from the list of framework assemblies, and allows the project to be built without the NuGet FSharp.Core assembly being replaced.

Until this fix is released into the SDK, there is a workaround. The answer submitted by user3850711 works, but you need to apply the changes in a specific sequence, because otherwise the reference will be overwritten during the build.

1. Delete the existing reference to `FSharp.Core`.
2. Install or reinstall the `FSharp.Core` NuGet package.
3. Unload the project and add   `<HintPath>packages\FSharp.Core.4.0.0.1\lib\portable-net45+monoandroid10+monotouch10+xamarinios10\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>` to the `FSharp.Core` project reference.